# Фокуса на поле недостаточно

Tags: дефект, предложение, инструменты-модератора

При нажатии на радиобаттон для преобразования ответа в комментарий фокус ставится на поле ввода, но текст в нём не выделяется. Это промежуточное поведение несёт довольно мало пользы, поскольку есть два возможных варианта моего поведения - либо мне действительно надо перенести к вопросу (тогда фокусировка поля вообще не имеет значения), либо мне надо перенести к ответу - но в этом случае если я нажму Ctrl+V, то помимо вставленного текста останется и текст про вопрос.

Предлагаю помимо фокусировки на поле выделять весь текст, находящийся в нём, чтобы при нажатии Ctrl+V он заменялся на вставляемую ссылку.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Абсолютно согласен, уже напарывался на это несколько раз.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, раньше ж выделялось?

Comment: Не уверен, что когда-то было по-другому. Точно знаю, что несколько раз в этом году ругался на то что, вроде вставил ID ответа - а оно не стерло ID вопроса и получилась каша.